# Can't Move Tab to Desired Position

Tags: excel, vba

I started out with

```
With Wb.Worksheets
    Set Fun = .Add(Before:=.Item(1))
End With
```

Then continued with

```
With Wb.Worksheets
    .Add(Before:=.Item(1))
End With

With ActiveSheet
    .Move Before:=Wb.Worksheets(1)
End With
```

And now I'm at

```
With Wb.Worksheets.Add
    .Move Before:=Wb.Worksheets(1)
End with
```

None of them inserts the sheet in the position of the first tab. In fact, the very beginning was that the sheet was added to another workbook also open at the time (the one containing the code), also in the wrong position. I cured that by activating `Wb`. I don't understand why that would be necessary but the problem seems to have gone away and changing the ActiveWorkbook doesn't bother me. Having the new sheet in the wrong position does.

Regardless of how I create or attempt to move it, the sheet will always appear in the same position which is NOT before the ActiveSheet, and stay there. It's always the next to last sheet. It chooses that position in either of two different workbooks I tried, one of them saved, the other one never saved.

What am I missing? How can I move that new sheet to become the first tab in the workbook.

Comment: Are you sure that the first worksheet is 1? Generally while programming computers, the first one is 0.

Comment: Thank you @Dominique. The index of collections generally is 1-based. However, I did Debug.Print the name of `Wb.WorkSheets(1)` and can confirm that it's the name I expected it to be. The new sheet is not inserted before that sheet.

Comment: @Dominique In Excel actually most things start counting with `1` and not with `0`. So `Sheets(1)` is always the first sheet in the tab bar. Note that `Worksheets(1)` and `Sheets(1)` might not be the same sheet if there are for example chat sheets included in your workbook.

Comment: @Variatus Please check if `Sheets` works instead of `Worksheets`. Note that `Sheets` contains all sheet types (worksheets, chart sheets, …) but `Worksheets` contains only the worksheets. So if working with index numbers of the tab bar you should use `Sheets` to be more accurate. People often use `Sheets` and `Worksheets` likewise but they are actually complete different lists.

Comment: @PEH Thank you for looking into this. Actually, I am rather particular about the difference between `Sheets` and `Worksheets` but the solution seems to have been much simpler. While the sheet was added to the wrong workbook I started to interrupt the program to see what was going on and continued the practice after that problem was solved. Now that I let the program run to its end where it encounters `ScreenUpdating = True` the new sheet is shown where I want it to be.

Comment: `wb.Worksheets.Add Before:=wb.Worksheets(1)`  and then `Set Fun = wb.Worksheets(1)` worked for me

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes. It worked for me, too - during testing. Now it doesn't. The point is that Wb Is Not ThisWorkbook `And` ThisWorkbook has an open User Form `And` Wb may be open in a hidden window. I conclude that Excel doesn't support, or doesn't fully support, write-access to either workbooks other than the one having the form open in general and/or those that are in invisible windows, in particular.Opening such workbooks already requires a work-around (shown in my code). It might all be a matter of hitting the correct sequence. It might.

Comment: Yup. In my tests too, wb is not Thisworkbook.

Comment: Did you hear that mighty thud? That was the stone rolling off my heart.

Comment: Let me create couple of test scenarios and share that with you

Comment: For the record, my earlier experience that the problem would disappear when ScreenUpdating is restored was a fluke. A change of status of windows does occur when the form is closed which, in my project, happens at the same time. This thread has a continuation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572111/activate-a-workbook-invisibly-from-a-userform?noredirect=1#comment108946706_61572111

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213218/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-variatus).