# Activate a Workbook Invisibly from a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have been chewing on this problem for more than two weeks, including asking a question here but I got both the question and its solution wrong. So I want to try again.

I have a user form which I open in Excel. It lists all currently open workbooks and allows me to open additional ones. My program will add, modify or delete tables in any of the workbooks. Tables are required to be in worksheets of names the program generates. Such worksheets will be added if they don't exist. When a worksheet is added it's sorted into a particular location in the tab sequence depending upon its name. Each of these actions works on ThisWorkbook. I have difficulty ascertaining under which conditions some of them don't work on other workbooks and, therefore, can't find a cure.

Start with the form. It's called from a worksheet in ThisWorkbook. I had it modal. Now it's modeless. I haven't observed any difference. However, because of the sheer number of possibilities I have difficulty created a good way for comprehensive testing. I'm looking for knowledge that can save me a lot of trial and error time.

Workbooks are added with this code. As an aside, to the best of my knowledge suspending ScreenUpdating during this process is ineffective. It's setting the window to invisible that causes the effect.

```
Dim Fltr As String
Dim Ffn As Variant
Dim Fn() As String
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Fltr = "Excel Workbooks|*.xls*||All Excel files|*.xl*"
Ffn = FileOpenName("Select a Target Document", Fltr, , True)
If Not IsEmpty(Ffn) Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To UBound(Ffn)
        Fn = Split(Ffn(i), "\")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Wb = Workbooks(Fn(UBound(Fn)))
        If Err Then
            Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Ffn(i))
            ActiveWindow.Visible = False
        End If
    Next i
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

When the form is loaded ThisWorkbook is active. All other open workbooks are invisible. The effect of the above code is that new workbooks are invisible as well and ThisWorkbook remains active. Superficially there is no difference but that seems to be on the surface only.

When I want to add a sheet to another workbook that workbook must, apparently, be active. I have successfully done that with both the modal and modeless form but right now my code refuses to activate the workbook (`Wb.Activate` is ignored without notification) and the sheet gets added to ThisWorkbook. This is the code that adds the sheet.

```
Private Function CreateLibrary(Wb As Workbook, _
                               Frm As Modifier) As Worksheet
    ' SSY 052 ++ 26 Apr 2020

    Dim ClmWidth As Variant                     ' default column widths
    Dim C As Long

'    Windows(Wb.Name).Visible = True
    With Wb.Worksheets.Add
        With .Cells
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .WrapText = True

            ' Library font = Arial / Table font = Calibri
            With .Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 10
            End With
        End With

        ' set default widths
        ClmWidth = Array(8.43, 10.57, 52, 24, 24)
        For C = 0 To UBound(ClmWidth)
            .Columns(C + 1).ColumnWidth = ClmWidth(C)
        Next C

        .Rows.RowHeight = 12.75
        .Name = Frm.TbxLib.Value
    End With

    Set CreateLibrary = ActiveSheet
End Function
```

I think the reason is that I can't activate a workbook in an invisible window. I believe the reason it worked before was because the window was invisible although its Visible property was set to True. I think it was on a workbook which I didn't open, but one that was open when the form was called. Those workbooks aren't in invisible windows. Just, the windows aren't active. One of the problems is that Excel will activate the window in which a new workbook is opened. Therefore my above code should be wrong. I found the method on SO.

In my previous question on this subject I complained about new worksheets being added in the wrong location, sometimes ThisWorkbook instead of the designated one. I thought the problem would be solved by updating the screen. That wasn't true. The new sheet would be in the wrong workbook depending upon how the intended workbook was opened. My code simply added it to the ActiveWorkbook. But I still don't know why it's always in second to last position. I found that my code inserted (code to that effect) the worksheet before all others but a sorter was run immediately thereafter which might move the sheet again, depending upon which other sheets there are already in the workbook and, perhaps, move it to the ActiveWorkbook, too. I suspect that the sorter might give a problem depending upon whether the workbook is active or not and its window visible or hidden. The sorter works fine under normal circumstances but the effect of this is that I don't know whether the sheet is inserted in the correct position to begin with. Now I'm doing tests without the sorter but have a problem getting the sheet inserted at all.

I'm in a vicious circle and can't find the way out. I think, the form itself is at the core of my problem. Excel's VBA (2013) will have the form's workbook active by default. Having a modeless form and flipping through workbooks selected on that form isn't possible anymore. But that isn't what I want, either. I want all the workbooks, with the acceptable exception of ThisWorkbook, to stay in the background. I think my conundrum would become solvable if I could find a way to open additional workbooks and force them into the same technical position as workbooks which were already open when the form was opened - in visible but inactive windows. I read someone's advice to temporarily shut down the form and reload it but that seems like taking a hammer to swat a fly.

Edit:-
Meanwhile I have added the following code to the procedure above.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Dim Win As Window
    For Each Win In Application.Windows
        Debug.Print Win.Index, Win.Caption,
        Debug.Print Win Is ActiveWindow,
        Debug.Print Win.Visible
    Next Win
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It produces the following, astonishing result.

[image]

- Windows(1) is ThisWorkbook
- Windows(2) was open when the form was loaded
- The other 3 were added using the code above where I had changed `ActiveWindow.Visible = False` into `Windows(1).Visible = False`
  Windoes(1) is supposed to be the ActiveWindow, not (2). Windows(1) and (3) are, in fact, visible in the tabs row at the bottom of the Excel application but not the other 3, including #2 which was visible there before. Observe that these windows have no Visible property set. All of this changed when I closed the form. I ran the same code and got this printout, which also doesn't make sense. However, all 5 windows are now included in the tab bar at the bottom of the Excel window, obviously irrespective of their visibility status.

[image]

I also wonder what's the point of a modeless form in my context. It seems to be designed to allow switching of sheets of its own workbook. Therefore making no difference is the best case scenario. What's the worst?

Comment: A quick note... `and the sheet gets added to ThisWorkbook.` This will only happen if you do not fully qualify `Sheets.Add`. If you fully qualify it for ex `wbThat.Sheets.Add...` then the sheets will be added to the right workbook.

Comment: @Siddarth Rout Thank you for taking the time to look into my problem. There are restrictions at play here which are rooted in the visibility of the workbooks, their status as Active or Inactive and limitations imposed by the UserForm.

Comment: At first I specified the workbook but the sheet wasn't inserted. Then I tried to activate the targeted workbook and specified the ActiveWorkbook. That leads to the sheet being inserted in ThisWorkbook. My present research aims at finding out how I can activate a workbook other than the user form's (ThisWorkbook). Your advice as to which method to pursue would be helpful and a suggestion as to the point in my program where I should introduce change worth its weight in gold.

Comment: I wanted to help you but your first comment (deleted now) discouraged me :)  Anyways. I would like to see your sheets add code and also if possible (?) the workbook which has the code and the userform. And if you choose to share the workbook then do remember to remove any confidential data from it.

Comment: @Siddarthy Rout. Thanks for forgiving my faux pas. I shall greatly value your continued support. However, I would hate to receive a project like mine. It's just too complicated, meaning time consuming. Please ask any details you want to know and trust my answers as well as my testing. We can move this to a chat, if you show me how. The code to add the sheet is inconspicious and correct. However, if the target workbook isn't ThisWorkbook the sheet may not be added because either the workbook isn't the workbook defined as active by the user form or because the target is invisible.

Comment: If I try to activate a workbook the instruction isn't carried out either because the open user form prevents it or because the designated workbook isn't visible. I end up either with the sheet in ThisWorkbook or not at all. But I also added the sheet to another workbook successfully. That was (I forgot) a workbook already open when the form was loaded but I couldn't move that sheet to the location I wanted. Please look over the Debug.Prints I posted - before closing the form and after. There are two ActiveWorkbooks! You ought to be able to reconstruct that with the code I posted.

Comment: `The code to add the sheet is inconspicious and correct. However, if the target workbook isn't ThisWorkbook the sheet may not be added because either the workbook isn't the workbook defined as active by the user form or because the target is invisible.` Yes I would still like to see the code if that is ok so that I can create a minimal example at my end to reproduce the issue becuase like I said it doesn't matter if the workbook is visible/active or not if the sheets are added in the correct way. In the meantime Let me go through the other issues

Comment: I published the code here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381666/cant-move-tab-to-desired-position. Tell me if you want to see more of it. I'm reticent because I've been changing it a lot and, right now, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout In our chat, which I now can't find, I told you that the inserted sheet would be a copy from ThisWorkbook. This is a change I implemented after posting this question. Therefore it should be irrelevant here. I added the full (previous) code for adding a sheet to my question above.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Thank you for your help in this matter.  You were able to replicate the fault but failed to nail it down, just as happened to me. I still don't know what, exactly, your tests proved but they were a source of great encouragement to me. Thank you for that. I want you to know that the code that is now performing as designed is unchanged. The difference between then and now is that there is no open form and no workbooks that were opened with any degree of invisibility. Conditions, in other words, are much the same as in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether there is a solution to my problem it's apparent now that I won't find it. Therefore I have made the following determinations.

1. I shall close and unload the user form when the user clicks the OK button. I hope that this will eliminate whatever difference exists between visible and invisible windows and allow me to activate whichever one I want.
2. I shall activate the workbook the user selected in the form and make its window active and visible, hoping for no more interference in that process once the user form is closed and unloaded.
3. I shall cease playing with a modeless user form. Its modality appears to make no difference to my ability to access workbooks. It looks and smells like a red herring.

---

======== Edit May 18, 2020
I have implemented the above steps and got the project to work as intended. My final verdict on the problem is that it was caused by **the presence of an open user form which prevented activating other workbooks**. All other issues were side effects of this.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I would have probable made the following changes:

instead of `With Wb.Worksheets.Add`
I would have done:
 `wb.sheets.add.name = "bob"`
or
 `wb.sheets.add (before:=wb.sheets(1)).name = "bob"`
or replace the sheets(1) with sheets("neil")

then you can do `with wb.sheets("bob")` - stay away from both activeworkbook and activesheet.

I'm pretty sure `if Err then` isnt working - Err is an object not a boolean variable.  so maybe it should be `If Err.Number <> 0 then`  an you would need to include `Err.Clear` before the loop and after any time you get an error or you will go into the If statement for each reiteration of the loop

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Assigning the name to the new worksheet in one line is neat. Indeed the Err object's default property is the .Number. `If [any number <>0]` evaluates to True. Therefore the `<> 0` isn't, strictly, required. `On Error Resume Next` resets the Err object, same as `Err.Clear`. In the loop, it therefore takes the latter's place.